# for loop only get executed once | bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to code a simple renaming script. But Im running into the issue that the loop only gets executed onces. The `$folder` consist of 6 lines with values.

```
echo "Start Episode?"
read start_ep
echo "Start Season?"
read start_se
echo "$folder"
for entry in "$folder"
do
    rename_array+="S${start_se}E${start_ep}"
    let "start_ep++"
    echo "$start_ep"
done
echo "Hello"
echo ${rename_array[*]}
```

Expected output:

```
Start Episode?
1
Start Season?
1
/home/georodin/01.txt
/home/georodin/02.txt
/home/georodin/03.txt
/home/georodin/04.txt
/home/georodin/05.txt
/home/georodin/06.txt
2
3
4
5
6
Hello
S1E1
S1E2
S1E3
S1E4
S1E5
S1E6
```

Output:

```
Start Episode?
1
Start Season?
1
/home/georodin/01.txt
/home/georodin/02.txt
/home/georodin/03.txt
/home/georodin/04.txt
/home/georodin/05.txt
/home/georodin/06.txt
2
Hello
S1E1
```

Comment: Look at the bash man-page: The syntax is `for name in word ....`, and the loop is executed for each word in the line (after possible parameter- or filename expansion). You have only one word, so the loop is executed once, with `entry` set to `$folder`.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to turn `folder` into an array, with one array element for each folder to process?

Comment: thank you for your input, I stick with the answer below but I will keep your suggestion in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$folder` contains new lines, try the loop like that:

```
while IFS= read -r entry; do
    echo "... $entry ..."
done <<< "$folder"
```

**Edit**: See also [Bash: Iterating over lines in a variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I think the double quote make $folder like one item in the for loop. Delete them !

```
for entry in $folder
do
    rename_array+="S${start_se}E${start_ep}"
    let "start_ep++"
    echo "$start_ep"
done
```

This should work with your initial idea.
Be careful with quotes in bash they are very powerful :)